# Não consigo fazer um elemento ter um wrap em um layout responsivo

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, float, flexbox

Boa tarde, estou tentando tornar um layout responsivo mas não consigo fazer a descrição do produto ir para debaixo da imagem quando o espaço disponível for pequeno demais. Já tentei com display:flex e com float mas nenhum funcionou.

Segue o link da página em questão:

http://www.hominumstore.com.br/pd-489292-direito.html?ct=&p=1&s=1

Comment: Você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar uma media querie para controlar a tela, segue exemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {   
     //controlar as classes
     .logo {
         font-size: 20px;
     }
}
```

Nas imagens use max-width: 100%;